# How to determine that I'm back on index page in framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

Inside my `index.html`, I have this button that goes to `about.html` when tapped.

```
<div class="col-50">
    <a href="about.html">
        <div class="button">About</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And on about page, I would like to detect when`back` button is tapped and that I am now on my `index.html` page.

Here's what I've tried:

First attempt:

```
myApp.onPageInit('index', function (page) {
    myApp.alert("test");
});
```

Second attempt:

```
myApp.onPageInit('index', function (page) {
    myApp.alert("test");
}).trigger();
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
myApp.onPageBack("about", function() {
  myApp.alert("test");
});
```

Do not forget the `data-page="about"` attribute in your `about` page.

```
  <div class="pages">
    <div class="page" data-page="about">
      <div class="page-content">
        ... page content goes here ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I must be blind, I can't find this in the documentation. You really saved my day. Thanks man!